# Mock a calling method using Spock in Groovy

Tags: groovy, spock

I've a piece of line of code in one my class. I need to test this using groovy by mocking some object. But, anyways it goes into the method

My class has the following code

```
BBRequest bbRequest = getUpdatedRequst(payload);
```

getUpdatedRequest is one of the method which is a private one

Now coming to the groovy class, I'm trying to mock this one as

```
BBRequest newRequest= BBRequest .builder().build()

1 * getUpdatedRequst(*_) >> newRequest --> Here I want to compile the above line of class and gets assigned with the newRequest
```

How can I get this done

Comment: Please be advised to learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, then edit your question in order to produce one. You cannot seriously assume that with two one-line code snippets from different classes without any context anyone can answer your question. You will only attract lots of speculation at best. One more question before we continue: Am I assuming correctly that you never wrote a unit test before or at least never used a mock before? I like to know in order to later answer your question on the right level of abstraction. Thank you.

Comment: Options:1. Move the private method out to another class that can be injected into the class under test 2. Make the updateRequest method public/package-private so it can be tested